# How to add several weight painted vertex groups to a Geometry node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

`[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=L1RDw00O" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/L1RDw00O/)`[image]I am working on a forest scene, using geometry nodes. They work great for a single object such as grass or trees. But I am not able to combine them. I am able to weight paint a vertex group and that works well. Followed the donut tutorial.
I cannot get 2 vertex groups on the same geometry object. The ground plane for example.
I need to say have 1 weight paint vertex group for tall grass. Another for short. Another for weeds or flowers.
I am able to do this with particle groups. But geometry nodes will not allow a second weight paint. Not on the same object.
I know they are still building geometry nodes. Maybe its too early for what I need.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I cant get the weight paint to work and the group node comes out different. All the objects appear on the plane. But they do not follow the weight paint. Some thing here I do not get.

Comment: What exactly did you try?  Can you provide a blend file?

Comment: I tried to add a .blend file but can't find any way to do that.

Comment: You can push it to https://blend-exchange.com/ and link it here.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=L1RDw00O" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/L1RDw00O/)

Comment: Essentially your file works. But there are some things you can do, to make it work better:
All your weight paints differ only between a weight of 0.5 and 1.0. You will see more difference, when you set the low values to 0.
The weight is set to the vertices. Your plane only is 11x11. Thus your weights are distributed very roughly. Create more subdivisions.
You may increase the density. You may reduce the size of your objects.

Comment: Thanks again. It works exactly like you said.

Answer (score 2):

First add the vertex groups to the Vertex Groups panel and create your weight paints. In my example I created a plane with 22x22 vertices and added three groups.

[image: vertex groups]

Add the Geometry Node net to the object. In the Geometry Node net create one *Distribute Points on Faces* node for every vertex group. Connect the *Density* input of each of these nodes to a terminal of the Group Input.

[image: geometry nodes net]

Then press *n*, to show the panel on the right and choose the Group tab. Here you can provide names for each of the terminal of the Group Input.

[image: group tab]

Then connect select one group for each terminal of the Group Input in the modifier panel. Additionally I added a factor to control the number of points.

[image: modifier tab]

In my example I created cubes for one group, spheres for the next and cylinders for the third group.

[image: result]

[image]